# render ReactPortal inside ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What I want to achieve is to render a ReactPortal inside a ref, thus inside the React Application itself, and not a DOM node outside.

I've made a sort of example on Codepen -> https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/RqKZmM

```
class Legend extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.useRef)
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(<div className="legend">Something</div>, this.props.ref);
    else
      return <div className="legend">Something else</div>;
  }
}

class Chart extends React.Component {
  private myref;

  render() {
        return (
      <div>
        <div className="container" ref={r => this.myref = r}>First Container</div>
        <Legend ref={this.myref} useRef={false} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So, basically: inside Chart Component I save the ref of the first div, and then I pass that ref to the Legend Component.
Inside the Legend Component, if the props useRef is true, I want to use the createPortal() to return a div inside the Chart's div.

The problem is that React throw me error: TypeScript tells me that "Argument of type 'RefOject' is not assignable to parater of type 'Element'.

Now, I don't know if what I'm trying to do is even possible, but if it is, could you guys help me a little? Maybe I'm missing something with ref (some conversion, I guess, but I really don't know what to do).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must first make sure that your ref has been created, which it is when the component is first mounted. The `ref` prop is used internally by React much like the `key` prop, so you must name it something else and treat it like any other prop.

**Example**

```js
class Legend extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.useRef) {
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div className="legend">Something</div>,
        this.props.portalRef
      );
    }
    return <div className="legend">Something else</div>;
  }
}

class Chart extends React.Component {
  myref = null;
  state = { mounted: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    // The ref has been created when the component has mounted.
    this.setState({ mounted: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container" ref={r => this.myref = r}>
          First Container
        </div>
        {this.state.mounted && <Legend portalRef={this.myref} useRef />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: Maaan, you nailed it,  thanks!! One question: if the ref is not created, than I guess its value is null. So, it would be ok, inside the Legend Component, to just check if this.props.ref is different than null? Or this would be "bad manner"?

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo You're welcome! Yeah, just checking `if (this.props.portalRef) { ... }` would work fine.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go that way so I don't have to keep trace of the ref in the state and I avoid componentDidMount().. Although I'm thinking that the Component could not refresh (because now state change has been made, so the Legend Component may not re-render)

Comment: @MatteoGesmundo Yes, you're right. If you just use `<Legend portalRef={this.myref} />` without the `mounted` state, the `Legend` component will not know that `this.props.portalRef` has updated, since it's a mutable value.